# What is the wrap on a coffee mug or a thermos called?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

When I buy a cup of coffee for taking away, the seller usually wraps the cup with tissue for reducing the heat or coldness when I hold the cup in my hand. There are also thick wraps that are made of some kind of rubber for putting it around the coffee cup or a thermos for sales as well. Does it have a name or just call it a wrap?

Comment: Next time you buy a cup, ask the barista what it's called.

Comment: I am not in a country where all baristas know how to address things in English.

Comment: **Zarf**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarf

Comment: @PhilSweet -- *The zarf was often made from metal, with silver, gold, copper, and brass being the most common materials used. Others were also made of woods such as coconut, ebony or other hardwoods, or of ivory, bone, horn, or tortoiseshell.*

Comment: (I'm thinking that I've generally seen it referred to as a "wrap" or "cup warmer" or some other rather mundane term.)

Comment: But there is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_cup_sleeve).

Comment: Yes, basically, it can be made from anything and everything. If you are wondering if it applies to cardboard, google zarf, select "images", select "cardboard"

Comment: I've only ever heard it called a "sleeve" (in the US.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always thought of it as an "insulating sleeve."